# What is the support of a basis in a group algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I'm reading Peter Webb's Representation theory book. He refers to the support of a set a few times and it confuses me. I'll give an example with context:

Consider $k[gH]\cdot IH$ ($IH$ is the augmentation ideal of $H$, $k$ is a field, but it doesn't really matter), which has basis $ \{g(h-1)| h\in H\} $. The book says that this basis has support in $gH$. What does that mean? Would this be equivalent to saying that $g(h-1)\in k[gH]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *support* of an element $a = \sum_g a_g\, g$ of $kG$ is defined to be a set $\operatorname{supp} a = \{\, g \in G \mid a_g \neq 0 \,\}$ (see [Polcino Milies-Sehgal](https://books.google.com/books?id=7m9P9hM4pCQC&pg=PA129)). So I think "a basis has support in $gH$" means the support of every element of the basis is contained in $gH$; in other words, $\bigcup_{h \in H} \operatorname{supp} g(h-1) \subseteq gH$.